# Design pattern choice

Tags: python, python-2.7, design-patterns

It's often the case that I have a possible action, and I need to select among different ways to do it. Note that through the lifetime of the object, I will need to run the method only once.

One way to do it could be:

```
class A(object):
    def my_fun(self, identifier, *args, **kwargs):
        if identifier == 'fun1':
            return self.fun1(*args, **kwargs)
        elif identifier == 'fun2':
            return self.fun2(*args, **kwargs)
        ...

    def fun1(...):
        ...
    def fun2(...):
        ...
```

Another way that I think is nicer is to directly set the method:

```
class A(object):
    def my_fun(self, identifier, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def fun1(...):
        ...
    def fun2(...):
        ...


a = A()
a.my_fun = fun23
```

I think it's nicer because there is a lot less boilerplate code, adding a fun is just implementing it, rather than adding it as well in the my_fun. Also I can have a proper autocomplete when choosing the function.

However, I have not seen this way of doing things in other python code. Is it good practice? Are there other suggestions for doing this?

Comment: What's the python version you are using? I have used singledispatch in similar situations https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch

Comment: Are you aware of `getattr(obj, identifier)(*args, **kwargs)` as a possible simplification...?

Comment: @AnupamSaini I am on python2-7

Comment: @deceze: yes that would work, but would still not give me an autocomplete.

Comment: @DevShark Would a dictionary work? `funcs = {
        "fun1" : self.fun1,
        "fun2" : self.fun2
        }
        if identifier in funcs:
            return funcs[identifier](*args, **kwargs)` or similar?

Comment: Same thing, it is more code to write, and does not give me autocompletion.